# Spellcaster specializing in casting enchanting spells on allies weapons

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

Is there a class that can do this in Pathfinder and make it worth it? 3.5 is a maybe with DM approval.

I am looking to make a tiny sized cohort who will sit on my shoulder or something and enchant my gunslinger's guns while we fight.

My questions if this build is possible, is this build worth it or would it be horribly inefficient?

Homebrew classes are welcomed. I will read them over to be sure they are balanced but all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the transmutation spells that the wizard/sorc gets? There are plenty of buffs there many which specifically apply to guns/ammo.

Comment: @ColinD No I have not. Is transmutation one of the schools? I admit I have never played or built a wizard or sorcerer.

Comment: There are also feat trees that allow you to specialize in specific schools and master specific spells. Worth considering if you go the Wizard/Familiar path. You can truly specialize your character into a buffing, weapon enhancing master.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Artificer

I suggest the Artificer class. It's a base class, in the Eberron Campaign Setting, a D&D 3.5 book.

One of its main class abilities is "casting" so-called *Infusions*. Most of them specifically target items. For example, in situations where most normal casters would cast Bear's Endurance, an Artificer instead imbues a character's magical item with the power to bestow a similar bonus. There are numerous Infusions that deal with enhancing weapons, especially the Weapon Augmentation line of Infusions.

Note that while powerful, the Artificer class is difficult to play, often requiring large amounts of preparations and predictive ability to use in an effective manner. [This ongoing question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34288/how-can-i-play-an-artificer-predictively) deals with the issue.

A major weakness is the time it takes to create an Infusion - this is frequently one minute.

Comment: Possibly worth noting the Action Point to speed up infusion casting.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, It's Both Possible and Efficient

The [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership---final) feat is one of the game's best feats. Attracting a spellcaster as a cohort is boon to any character.

**Any Class Can Have a Little Buddy**
Any class can have a cohort--a specific NPC follower, often with class levels in player-character classes (rather than [NPC classes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/npc-classes)) and usually acquired *via* the feat Leadership--with the DM's permission *via* many different character options. *Acquiring* that permission can be challenging because, according to the rules, the DM manages the cohort yet the cohort's loyal to the PC who expended the resources aquiring it. This requires the DM to play an NPC who might be expected to be a near-constant PC companion while trying to inconvenience the PCs and all of their near-constant companions.

The PC who gains a cohort *attracts* one; such a creature does not come into being spontaneously with all the options the player desires merely because the PC takes the feat Leadership. As the DM builds and controls NPCs--and the cohort *is* an NPC--the usual process I've experienced is the player tells the DM what kind of cohort his PC is trying to attract and the *DM* builds the cohort.

A DM who allows players to build their characters' cohorts exhibits vast trust in his players.

**The Standard Class Choices**
An easily managed cohort is a blessing to the DM, but a cohort who casts spells usually isn't easily managed. I suggest a sorcerer, with its limited spells known, but what *you* probably want--and having either is *far* harder on the DM--is a cleric or wizard because of the cohort's versatility. It's one thing having a cohort who casts [*greater named bullet*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/named-bullet) 3/day but another thing entirely having a cohort who casts *[find the path](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/find-the-path)*, [*heal*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/heal), and *[heroes' feast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/heroes-feast)*, especially when no one else can. While you'll find the latter qualitatively better than the former, the former is more likely to meet with your DM's approval, especially if designed in the way you describe.

*Pathfinder* currently lacks an official character class specializing in item creation and modification, but third party classes that do so include a different, not *D&D 3.5* [artificer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/adamant-entertainment/artificer), and the [artisan](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/3rd-party-publisher---drop-dead-studios---classes/the-artisan), [gearhead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/icosa-entertainment-llc/gearhead), [machinesmith](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/louis-porter-jr-design/machinesmith), and [tinker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/interjection-games/tinker). Some are steampunk style inventors but often also possess at least some spellcasting.

**Getting a Tiny Cohort**
What would be awesome is if the game supported a shoulder dragon, winged mini-demon, or little tornado with arms that would cast spells to make your guns better and reload your guns when he's not busy spellcasting. Yeah, but the game doesn't support those.

The easiest option is a halfling or gnome sorcerer who has been the target of the spell [*reduce person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reduce-person) followed by a high-level casting of the spell [*permanency*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency). Such a creature is Tiny and *can* sit on a PC's shoulder. Alternately, a [monkey](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/primates/primate-monkey) who's been the target of the spell *[awaken](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken)* and subsequently gained sorcerer levels could serve the same purpose, but will likely be a lower-level spellcaster due to the increased HD from the spell *awaken*.

The [Monster Cohorts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-cohorts) page lists Young Dragon as an option, so your DM could house rule a [faerie dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon-faerie) (which doesn't have an age category) as a 10th-level cohort when your Leadership score hits 14, but the Leadership feat really, really hates letting monsters follow around PCs and the list encourages bigger monsters rather than smaller ones.

Another way to get a shoulder buddy is to use the rules for [Monsters as PCs](http://paizo.com/PRD/monsters/monstersAsPCs.html), which produces far superior and more playable results than the above CR 2 critter when you're level 12. Using those rules would allow for a shoulder dragon, winged mini-demon, or little tornado with arms cohort, but using those requires house rules as the cohort isn't a PC. Another house rule can be made to allow *building* a race that meets your needs from scratch using the rules for [Creating New Races](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races). I don't know enough about *Pathfinder*'s vast supply creatures to tell you if there's the perfect creature for your needs in an obscure sourcebook, however.